# Docker image TCP buffer size

Tags: networking, debian, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with a debian container in a cluster model. I'm starting a process in 3 containers that needs to communicate each other but during the process of initial communication an exception associated to the TCP buffer size its generated.

Following this post https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/236787/getting-warning-message-dcsv9413w-failed-to-set-bu/ I tried to change the settings `net.ipv4.tcp_rmem` and `net.ipv4.tcp_wmem` but they does not exist in the container, and reading another posts, it looks docker does not allow to change this kind of setting. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/664586/kernel-tuning-with-privileged-docker-container

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of docker do allow providing sysctl settings via the command line, e.g. `docker run --sysctl` (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime).

The two settings you need are supported (indeed, all net.* settings are supported), although you will need a recent docker release. 
See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4717 for some background.

Prior to that, however, your best (and only) bet was to configure the system accordingly, and have docker inherit the system's sysctl settings.